# Pandas Dataframe automatically changing from int8 to float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, memory

I have a very large matrix of 100K x 100K and to manage memory better, I am setting this as a dataframe with int8 as datatype (for 1 byte per cell). However, it gets set as a float with 8 bytes per cell. Where am I going wrong?

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df=df.astype('int8')  
mat_len=100,000

for i in range(0, mat_len):
    new_row = pd.Series([0] * mat_len)
    df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index='True') #initializing matrix
    
for i in range(0, mat_len):
    for j in range(i,mat_len):
        df.iloc[i,j] = i+j   #simplified calc for testing purposes
print(df.info())
```

**output**: dtypes: float64(100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the conversion inside your loop:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

mat_len=100

for i in range(0, mat_len):
    new_row = pd.Series([0] * mat_len)
    df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index='True')
    df=df.astype('int8')#initializing matrix
    
for i in range(0, mat_len):
    for j in range(i,mat_len):
        df.iloc[i,j] = i+j   #simplified calc for testing purposes
print(df.info())
```

which returns:

```
class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 100 entries, 0 to 99
Data columns (total 100 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   0       100 non-null    int8 
 1   1       100 non-null    int8 
 2   2       100 non-null    int8 
 3   3       100 non-null    int8 
 4   4       100 non-null    int8 
 5   5       100 non-null    int8 
 6   6       100 non-null    int8 
 7   7       100 non-null    int8 
 8   8       100 non-null    int8 
 9   9       100 non-null    int8 
 10  10      100 non-null    int8 
 11  11      100 non-null    int8 
 12  12      100 non-null    int8 
 13  13      100 non-null    int8 
 14  14      100 non-null    int8 
 15  15      100 non-null    int8 
 16  16      100 non-null    int8 
 17  17      100 non-null    int8 
 18  18      100 non-null    int8 
 19  19      100 non-null    int8 
 20  20      100 non-null    int8 
 21  21      100 non-null    int8 
 22  22      100 non-null    int8 
 23  23      100 non-null    int8 
 24  24      100 non-null    int8 
 25  25      100 non-null    int8 
 26  26      100 non-null    int8 
 27  27      100 non-null    int8 
 28  28      100 non-null    int8 
 29  29      100 non-null    int8 
 30  30      100 non-null    int8 
 31  31      100 non-null    int8 
 32  32      100 non-null    int8 
 33  33      100 non-null    int8 
 34  34      100 non-null    int8 
 35  35      100 non-null    int8 
 36  36      100 non-null    int8 
 37  37      100 non-null    int8 
 38  38      100 non-null    int8 
 39  39      100 non-null    int8 
 40  40      100 non-null    int8 
 41  41      100 non-null    int8 
 42  42      100 non-null    int8 
 43  43      100 non-null    int8 
 44  44      100 non-null    int8 
 45  45      100 non-null    int8 
 46  46      100 non-null    int8 
 47  47      100 non-null    int8 
 48  48      100 non-null    int8 
 49  49      100 non-null    int8 
 50  50      100 non-null    int8 
 51  51      100 non-null    int8 
 52  52      100 non-null    int8 
 53  53      100 non-null    int8 
 54  54      100 non-null    int8 
 55  55      100 non-null    int8 
 56  56      100 non-null    int8 
 57  57      100 non-null    int8 
 58  58      100 non-null    int8 
 59  59      100 non-null    int8 
 60  60      100 non-null    int8 
 61  61      100 non-null    int8 
 62  62      100 non-null    int8 
 63  63      100 non-null    int8 
 64  64      100 non-null    int8 
 65  65      100 non-null    int8 
 66  66      100 non-null    int8 
 67  67      100 non-null    int8 
 68  68      100 non-null    int8 
 69  69      100 non-null    int8 
 70  70      100 non-null    int8 
 71  71      100 non-null    int8 
 72  72      100 non-null    int8 
 73  73      100 non-null    int8 
 74  74      100 non-null    int8 
 75  75      100 non-null    int8 
 76  76      100 non-null    int8 
 77  77      100 non-null    int8 
 78  78      100 non-null    int8 
 79  79      100 non-null    int8 
 80  80      100 non-null    int8 
 81  81      100 non-null    int8 
 82  82      100 non-null    int8 
 83  83      100 non-null    int8 
 84  84      100 non-null    int8 
 85  85      100 non-null    int8 
 86  86      100 non-null    int8 
 87  87      100 non-null    int8 
 88  88      100 non-null    int8 
 89  89      100 non-null    int8 
 90  90      100 non-null    int8 
 91  91      100 non-null    int8 
 92  92      100 non-null    int8 
 93  93      100 non-null    int8 
 94  94      100 non-null    int8 
 95  95      100 non-null    int8 
 96  96      100 non-null    int8 
 97  97      100 non-null    int8 
 98  98      100 non-null    int8 
 99  99      100 non-null    int8 
dtypes: int8(100)
memory usage: 9.9 KB
None
​
```

Answer (score 2):

You should always avoid `append` to DataFrames/Series, especially avoid using it in a loop. It's very very slow. First, generate the data and then create a DataFrame with it.

> df.iloc[i,j] = i+j   #simplified calc for testing purposes

How complex is your calculation? In this simple case, your code can be highly simplified and optimized, by using [`numpy.fromfunction`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html)
and [`numpy.triu`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html)

```
mat_len = 100_000
# create matrix from a function of the indicies 
mat = np.fromfunction(lambda i,j: i+j, shape=(mat_len, mat_len), dtype='int8')
# make it an upper triangular matrix 
mat = np.triu(mat)
# create a DataFrame with it  
df = pd.DataFrame(mat)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't make things complicated, use numpy:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((100,100), dtype='int8'))
```

```
>>> df.dtypes
0     int8
1     int8
2     int8
3     int8
4     int8
      ... 
95    int8
96    int8
97    int8
98    int8
99    int8
Length: 100, dtype: object
```